# Can I Make Real Useful Desktop Program Using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, software-distribution

I've Learned C# Using Visual Studio For Long Enough. It's So Fun and Easy To Code and Learn Programming Using Visual Studio IDE. But Sometimes, I Ever Think To Make A Real Program That Useful Like Usually Software. Could I Make Good Software Just Using Visual Studio ? and If Yes, What's The Shortage of A Software That Develop Using Visual Studio ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course you can create a "real" program using Visual Studio. Visual Studio is one of the biggest IDE (Integrated Development Environment) out there.

For example Microsoft is using Visual Studio to create all of their Applications.
Office, Exchange, Windows and the list goes on.

If you want to create useful software with Visual Studio and C# think small in the beginning. Try to create applications that help YOU with whatever you do at your pc, because if you are able to create software that is useful to you, then it might be useful for others too, right?

Everybody starts out small and works his/her way up.